# Best practice interaction between application and LDAP

Tags: ldap

Lets say I've got an application which is using users from LDAP (I'm not talking about authentication).

I'm for example, using theses users as author of documents I'm filling in forms. 
I need to search them and display the informations of these users. I'm not needing fresh info (1 day is ok).

What's the best practice ?

1. Always query my LDAP to get my user ?
2. Daily synchronize my application to the LDAP to prevent overloading the LDAP ?

Basically, my question is : is the ldap made for regular queries of should we only use it for delta synchronization ?

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the type of application.

> Always query my LDAP to get my user ?

LDAP is characterised as write-once-read-many-times.  LDAP is used where in the data doesn't change in most cases. It is used for such operations where in you query LDAP a lot, like searching for a user whose name starts with 's', searching for users who are managers in your organizations.

> Daily synchronize my application to the LDAP to prevent overloading the LDAP ?

If you don't really have search in your application it is best to implement cache with TTL or on demand cache.

Comment: So you mean that ldap is designed to get a lot of read from an application ? That would make solution 1 better for my example.

Comment: yes, that's right. Imagine if your users were in a database, implementing search would be a big task. Though write operations are fast with DB when compared to LDAP, it beats when you look at the options in which the data can be queried.

Comment: Ok, that's interresting. In my case I was more thinking about the problematic of retrieving information from the user id (firstName, lastName, email, etc) than making a query with complex parameters. But this seems still relevant.